# Is giving the version number of next version of app as 1.0 allowed in app store while the current version number is 3.0?

Tags: iphone, app-store, version

I have an app in app store with version number 3.0, my manager wants the version number of next release to be 1.0, so is it permitted in app store?

Comment: Your manager should be smacked.

Comment: Does he at least *attempt* to give rational reasons for such requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should tell your manager --- "It is very impractical to do that, and it will cause a LOT of trouble."

Here's a suggestion: **call the new version "Version 10"**.  It sounds like a "start over," an important new product, which is likely what your manager is looking for. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Version numbers should usually be sequential, however the key question here is if you are currently on version 3.0 did you originally use 1.0 already for the first release of your app? Itunes Connect will only allow unique version numbers